# mysql: ERROR 1217 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql, error-handling, foreign-keys

```
drop table if exists Users;
drop table if exists Item;
drop table if exists Bid;
drop table if exists Category;

create table Users (
    userID varchar(200),
    rating integer,
    location varchar(255),
    country varchar(150),
    PRIMARY KEY(userID)
);

create table Item (
    itemID integer,
    name varchar(100),
    currently float,
    buy_price float,
    first_bid float,
    started timestamp,
    ends timestamp,
    userID varchar(200),
    description varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(itemID),
    FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES Users(userID)
);

create table Bid (
    itemID integer,
    userID varchar(200),
    time varchar(180),
    amount float,
    PRIMARY KEY(itemID,time),
    FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES Users(userID),
    FOREIGN KEY (itemID) REFERENCES Item(itemID)
);

create table Category(
    itemID integer,
    categoryID varchar(220),
    PRIMARY KEY(itemID,categoryID),
    FOREIGN KEY (itemID) REFERENCES Item(itemID)
);
```

I have a database named klyu. Above is a file named create.sql, when i run

```
source create.sql
```

in mysql, it returns

```
ERROR 1217 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign   key constraint fails
ERROR 1217 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.17 sec)

ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table 'Users' already exists
ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table 'Item' already exists
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
```

I saw some guy say check this via using SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS after drop fails, however, when i run this, it says ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need the PROCESS privilege for this operation

I have checked very carefully and read manual of foreign keys, but i still cannot find where is the problem.

Comment: When you try to create a table Item and reference with user ID as foreign key and the User table is still not created, you are facing this error. You have to reorder the script. Please check answer below.

Comment: Please mark as answered, if it answers your query,.

Comment: sorry can you tell me where is the button to mark? thanks

Comment: To mark as answered, There is a tick button to the left of the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you try to create a table Item and reference with user ID as foreign key and the User table is still not created, you are facing this error. Refer this - [MySQL - FOREIGN KEY Constraints Documentation:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

You have to reorder the script.

```
drop table if exists Item;
drop table if exists Users;
drop table if exists Bid;
drop table if exists Category; 

create table Users (
    userID varchar(200),
    rating integer,
    location varchar(255),
    country varchar(150),
    PRIMARY KEY(userID)
)   ENGINE=INNODB;

create table Item (
    itemID integer,
    name varchar(100),
    currently float,
    buy_price float,
    first_bid float,
    started timestamp,
    ends timestamp,
    userID varchar(200),
    description varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(itemID),
    FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES Users(userID)
)   ENGINE=INNODB;


create table Bid (
    itemID integer,
    userID varchar(200),
    time varchar(180),
    amount float,
    PRIMARY KEY(itemID,time),
    FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES Users(userID),
    FOREIGN KEY (itemID) REFERENCES Item(itemID)
)   ENGINE=INNODB;

create table Category(
    itemID integer,
    categoryID varchar(220),
    PRIMARY KEY(itemID,categoryID),
    FOREIGN KEY (itemID) REFERENCES Item(itemID)
)   ENGINE=INNODB;
```